# How to get url params in NextJs like: userid/:this_is_a_param

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

i'm having trouble trying to get url params with nextJs.
so similar to i'd usually do with express i'd like to get a :param from the url
like so

```
users/:userid/
console.log(req.params.userid)
```

all i could do is get the "userid" from url like so ?userid=
i'm also using typescript

Comment: Where are you trying to retrieve the URL parameter? Client-side or server-side? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the place that you need this parameters.

For **Client side** , you have to use `useRouter` hook.

For **getStaticProps** and **getServerSideProps** you have to use `context` object that is passed to this functions automatically.

For **Api Routes** , it's exactlly like `express js` and you can use `req.params.userid`

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you want to get the "userid" path variable from the respective page.

If the path `users/[userid].tsx` is a page, then it would look like this:

**/pages/users/[userid].tsx**:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { NextPage } from 'next'

const UserPage: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { userid } = router.query

  // TODO

  return <></>
}

export default UserPage
```

However, if you want to use the route as an API route, then it looks like this:

**/pages/users/[userid].ts**:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { userid } = req.query

  // TODO

  res.status(200).json({ name: `User ID: ${userid}` })
}
```